# Alert not showing when called within a callback using DispatchQueue

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to show alert when I receive an error when calling some API.

First I tried to call the alert without `DispatchQueue.main` but then I was getting an error that I can't call it from the background process.

My code now looks like this:

```
func activate(code: String, callback: () -> Void, errorCallback: @escaping () -> Void) -> Void {
        let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore (value: 0)

        let json: [String: String?] = ["phone_number": MySession.shared().get()?.phoneNumber, "code": code]
        let postData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)

        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "\(API_URL)/users/activate")!, timeoutInterval: 10)
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = postData

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if error != nil {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print("test error callback 1")
                    errorCallback()
                }
                return
            }

            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, (200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print("test error callback")
                    errorCallback()
                }
                return
            }

            let responseObject = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String: Any]
            MySession.shared().set(object: responseObject ?? nil)
            print(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)!)

            semaphore.signal()
        }

        task.resume()
        semaphore.wait()

        callback()
    }
```

And this is how I call it

```
AuthService.shared().activate(code: activationCode!, callback: {
            let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Home", bundle: nil)
            let homeViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeVC") as! HomeViewController
            homeViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            self.present(homeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }, errorCallback: {
            self.alertError(errorTitle: "", errorText: NSLocalizedString("Wrong activation code", comment: "Signup"))
        })
```

I am checking the log and I can't see the log that I added under `DispatchQueue.main.async`.

If I add a log above `DispatchQueue.main.async` then I can see the log. But I am not able to show the alert. Any suggestions?

Comment: Call `callback` from within the session task closure. Don't use a semaphore to block the main thread and wait. This looks like the bad code that Postman generates.

Comment: Kindly curious. Why are you using a completion call back and return at same time in same function?

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes, it is a postman generated code that I am trying to adjust.

Comment: The `callback` call works fine. The `errorCallback` and `print("test error callback")`
 is never triggered (everything under `DispatchQueue.main.async`)

Comment: @Paulw11 If I move `callback` to be called within the session task closure, then it doesn't open the VC that I am expecting. So it gets to the same problem like for `errorClosure` where the alert is not showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Postman doesn't generate very good template code.

It tries to use a semaphore to turn the asynchronous operation into a synchronouss one.  It also uses `try ?` rather than a proper `do/try/catch` so errors will be swallowed instead of reported.

You can use a `Result` type to combine the success and error callbacks.

UI operations such as presenting a new view or an error alert should be in the callback closure, not in the network operation itself.  This is also true of processing the data returned by the operation:

```
func activate(code: String, callback: @escaping ((Result<[String:Any],Error>)->Void)) {

    let json: [String: String?] = ["phone_number": MySession.shared().get()?.phoneNumber, "code": code]
    let postData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)

    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "\(API_URL)/users/activate")!, timeoutInterval: 10)
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = postData

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        if let error = error {
            callback(.failure(error))
            return
        }

        do {
            if let responseObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String: Any] {
                callback(.success(responseObject))
                return
            }
        } catch {
            callback(.failure(error))
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

Then to call it:

```
AuthService.shared().activate(code: activationCode!) { result in 
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        switch result {
           case .failure (let error):
                self.alertError(errorTitle: "", errorText: NSLocalizedString("Wrong activation code \(error)", comment: "Signup"))
           case .success (let result):
               MySession.shared().set(object: result)
               let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Home", bundle: nil)
               let homeViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeVC") as! HomeViewController
               homeViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
               self.present(homeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

A further improvement would be to create an appropriate struct and use that with `Codable` instead of a dictionary.